# Two horizontal bar charts with shared axis in ggplot2 (similar to population pyramid)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot two variables on one plot similar to a population pyramid similar to this:

[image: plot]

This plot is *almost* there but not quite, for the reasons I will list below.

I produced this plot with the following code:

```
DATA <- data.frame(
    state = c("AK", "TX", "CA", "MT", "NM", "AZ", "NV", "CO", "OR", "WY", "MI", "MN", "UT", "ID", "KS", "NE", "SD", "WA", "ND", "OK"),
    sales_staff = c(20,30,40,10,15,35,18,25,22,7,12,22,3,4,5,8,14,28,24,32)
)

set.seed(1)
DATA$sales <- DATA$sales_staff * 50 + (runif(nrow(DATA)) * 1000)

# Order the state factor by number of sales staff so that it is plotted in that order
DATA$state <- factor(DATA$state, levels = DATA[order(DATA$sales_staff),"state"])
```

I want to "glue" two plots back-to-back, so I use the multiplot() function verbatim from http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Multiple_graphs_on_one_page_%28ggplot2%29/

(I won't reproduce the code for that function here for brevity and clarity)

My code for the final plot is:

```
library(ggplot2)

g1 <- ggplot(data = DATA, aes(x = state, y = sales_staff)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + ggtitle("Number of sales staff") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), plot.margin = unit(c(1,0,1,0), "mm")) +
  scale_y_reverse() + coord_flip()

g2 <- ggplot(data = DATA, aes(x = state, y = sales)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + ggtitle("Sales (x $1000)") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), plot.margin = unit(c(1,5,1,0), "mm")) +
  coord_flip()

multiplot(g1, g2, cols = 2)
```

OK. So what's wrong with this plot?

- I need to get the tick marks on the right-axis of the left plot. I can't figure out how to do that.
- The two plots are different widths. This is because the states down the middle are the axis labels from the right plot and use some of the space for that plot.

I've hit a brick wall in getting this plot to "production quality". I'm starting to wonder if I'm going about this in the wrong way because I'm thinking the next step will be to draw the axis labels as a separate third column between the two plots. (I don't yet know how to do this). This will solve the "equal size" issue and permit me to add a "state" title, so it may still be the way to go. But I just can't help but wonder if there is a simpler way...

Any advice or assistance appreciated!

Comment: Can you adjust http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14680075/simpler-population-pyramid-in-ggplot2?lq=1 for your purpose?

Comment: I am a diehard `ggplot2` fan and use the package for absolutely everything I can, but when I needed to create a pyramid plot similar to the one above a few months back I eventually gave up and used `pyramid.plot` from the `plotrix` package. No, I didn't like the syntax, but it wasn't hard and I got better results than with `ggplot2` and with far less messing around.

Comment: You should search for "back to back charts".

Comment: There is a recently added, excellent demonstration of how to fine tune a `ggplot2` back-to-back bar chart: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37374271/3817004

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here is very long workaround for your plot. Idea is to create new plot that contains only state names and ticks on both sides and then use this as the middle plot.

For this plot I added title with no name to get space and `ylab(NULL)` to remove space. For left and right margin values are -1 to get plot closer to other plots. Library `grid` should be added before plotting to use function `unit()` for plot margins.

```
library(grid)
g.mid<-ggplot(DATA,aes(x=1,y=state))+geom_text(aes(label=state))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=0.94,xend=0.96,yend=state))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=1.04,xend=1.065,yend=state))+
  ggtitle("")+
  ylab(NULL)+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0),limits=c(0.94,1.065))+
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        panel.background=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(color=NA),
        axis.ticks.x=element_line(color=NA),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,-1,1,-1), "mm"))
```

Both original plots are modified. First, removed the y axis for the second plot and also made left/right margin to -1.

```
g1 <- ggplot(data = DATA, aes(x = state, y = sales_staff)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + ggtitle("Number of sales staff") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,-1,1,0), "mm")) +
  scale_y_reverse() + coord_flip()

g2 <- ggplot(data = DATA, aes(x = state, y = sales)) +xlab(NULL)+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + ggtitle("Sales (x $1000)") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,0,1,-1), "mm")) +
  coord_flip()
```

Now use library `gridExtra` and function d `grid.arrange()` to join plots. Before plotting all plots are made as grobs.

```
library(gridExtra)
gg1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1))
gg2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g2))
gg.mid <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g.mid))

grid.arrange(gg1,gg.mid,gg2,ncol=3,widths=c(4/9,1/9,4/9))
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for copious amounts of effort! And obviously for answering the OP

Comment: Something similar has been suggested by Prasad http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559229/drawing-pyramid-plot-using-r-and-ggplot2

Comment: We have a saying in Slovenia that goes along the lines of "if you don't use your head, you use your feet". :)

Comment: Nice. But you should load the `gridExtra` library before you create `g.mid` because the `unit` function comes from the `grid` package.

Comment: @idzis Elferts how can one add a text label under both sides ? or how to increase the size of the `axis`?