# How to make comparative two-way bar graphs on matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[Two way bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLf9t.png) this is a link to the image for a two way bar chart.

I am having a hard time making the lengths of the bars relative to one another and making the bars face different directions on matplotlib like the one shown above.

Comment: I like this post. I also watched this game earlier but cavs lost. Are you a cavs fan too? Btw, is it ok to use the NBA logo in your project?

Comment: @anonyXmous I'm not using the logo, but just wanting to create a graph like this. I am a big follower of the NBA and the Lakers are my favorite team

Comment: I see. That is why brown mamba instead of Kobe's monicker name. Btw, i found this SO post but axis is using vertical axis. You may take a look and modify it to use hirizontal axis instead. Goodluck. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27694221/using-python-libraries-to-plot-two-horizontal-bar-charts-sharing-same-y-axis