# how can I make my data side by side barplot with dots

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have read this post [Two horizontal bar charts with shared axis in ggplot2 (similar to population pyramid)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265941/two-horizontal-bar-charts-with-shared-axis-in-ggplot2-similar-to-population-pyr) and similar ones which could not help me to solve my problem because my data is different. Where I try to explain below

I have a data like below

```
    dfm<- structure(list(Var1 = structure(1:35, .Label = c("F10", "F11", 
"F12", "F13", "F14", "F15", "F16", "F18", "F19", "F2", "F21", 
"F25", "F3", "F30", "F35", "F4", "F5", "F58", "F6", "F60", "F7", 
"F79", "F8", "F9", "F97", "F117", "F17", "F22", "F23", "F26", 
"F31", "F41", "F61", "F67", "F87"), class = "factor"), Freq.x = c(4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 252L, 1L, 2L, 106L, 1L, 1L, 56L, 
32L, 1L, 28L, 1L, 17L, 1L, 10L, 7L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), Freq.y = c(12L, 3L, 6L, NA, 7L, NA, 1L, NA, 
2L, 306L, 1L, 2L, 170L, NA, NA, 69L, 45L, NA, 35L, NA, 20L, NA, 
13L, 7L, NA, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("Var1", 
"Freq.x", "Freq.y"), row.names = c(NA, -35L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have a mutual column named Var1 and two columns Freq.x and Freq.y 
I want to plot barplot in vertical ways and put a `red` or `blue`dot in top of each bar.

I want to plot the Freq.x in the right side, Freq.y in the left side and the F2 to ... in the middle of both as Y axis

Something like this

[image]

I have tried many things but I could not make it.

The closest I got is with the following code

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
barplot(dfm$Freq.y,axes=F,horiz=T,axisnames=FALSE)
axis(side=1,at=seq(1,252,50))
barplot(dfm$Freq.x,horiz=T,axes=T,las=1)
```

If you just plot the figure as the post mentioned above,
you see that it is giving wrong figure for my data
for example

```
library(grid)
g.mid<-ggplot(dfm,aes(x=1,y=Var1))+geom_text(aes(label=Var1))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=0.94,xend=0.96,yend=Var1))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=1.04,xend=1.065,yend=Var1))+
  ggtitle("")+
  ylab(NULL)+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0),limits=c(0.94,1.065))+
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        panel.background=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(color=NA),
        axis.ticks.x=element_line(color=NA),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,-1,1,-1), "mm"))


g1 <- ggplot(data = dfm, aes(x = Var1, y = Freq.x)) + 
geom_bar(stat = "identity") + ggtitle("Number of sales staff") + 
theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
plot.margin = unit(c(1,-1,1,0), "mm")) + 
scale_y_reverse() + coord_flip() 

g2 <- ggplot(data = dfm, aes(x = Var1, y = Freq.y)) +xlab(NULL)+ 
geom_bar(stat = "identity") + ggtitle("Sales (x $1000)") + 
theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
plot.margin = unit(c(1,0,1,-1), "mm")) + 
coord_flip() 

library(gridExtra) 
gg1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1)) 
gg2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g2)) 
gg.mid <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g.mid)) 

grid.arrange(gg1,gg.mid,gg2,ncol=3,widths=c(4/9,1/9,4/9))
```

[image]
See the plot
and look at for example the F2 values for both dfs
you see? both are the highest values but in this plot they show the least
about the second answer. they guy Melted the data and it made me crazy to melt my data
so I could not figure it out how to plot it based on that
about the third, it is completely out of my interest because I only need one plot with my data and not splitting it

after assigning the g.mid , it does not take the order into account , it starts from 87 to the end while the order of my `dfm`starts from 2

[image]

Comment: where is your g.mid defined?

Comment: @sandipan I added that above, but there are many problems with this . for example it is good if one knows the range of data and it is not assigning the right values to the right `yaxis`etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the red and blue dots. You can add `+geom_point(aes(x = Var1, y = Freq.x),shape=19,size=6,color="red")+`and `geom_point(aes(x = Var1, y = Freq.y),shape=19,size=6,color="blue")+`. Try this code (with @cuttlefish44 's help):

```
library(dplyr)
ind <- gsub("F", "", dfm$Var1) %>% as.numeric() %>% order(decreasing = T)
newlev <- levels(dfm$Var1)[ind]
dfm$Var1 <- factor(dfm$Var1, levels = newlev)
library(grid)
g.mid<-ggplot(dfm,aes(x=1,y=Var1))+geom_text(aes(label=Var1))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=0.94,xend=0.96,yend=Var1))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=1.04,xend=1.065,yend=Var1))+
  ggtitle("")+
  ylab(NULL)+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0),limits=c(0.94,1.065))+
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        panel.background=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(color=NA),
        axis.ticks.x=element_line(color=NA),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,-1,1,-1), "mm"))
g1 <- ggplot(data = dfm, aes(x = Var1, y = Freq.x)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + ggtitle("Number of sales staff") + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Var1, y = Freq.x),shape=19,size=6,color="red")+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,-1,1,0), "mm")) + 
  scale_y_reverse() + coord_flip() 
g2 <- ggplot(data = dfm, aes(x = Var1, y = Freq.y)) +xlab(NULL)+ 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + ggtitle("Sales (x $1000)") + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Var1, y = Freq.y),shape=19,size=6,color="blue")+
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,0,1,-1), "mm")) + 
  coord_flip() 
library(gridExtra) 
gg1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1)) 
gg2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g2)) 
gg.mid <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g.mid)) 

grid.arrange(gg1,gg.mid,gg2,ncol=3,widths=c(4/9,1/9,4/9))
```

[image]

**UPDATE Nº4**

In this example, I modify the labels. Try this code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
ind <- gsub("F", "", dfm$Var1) %>% as.numeric() %>% order(decreasing = T)
newlev <- levels(dfm$Var1)[ind]
dfm$Var1 <- factor(dfm$Var1, levels = newlev)
#labeling 35 levels to 7 levels
library(plyr)
each5<-levels(dfm$Var1)
interval<-rep(c(rep(c(FALSE),each=4),TRUE),length.out= 35)
dfm$Var2<-c("")
for (i in 1:length(dfm$Var1)){
  if (dfm$Var1[i] %in% each5[interval])
      dfm$Var2[i]<-as.character(dfm$Var1[i])
}
library(grid)
g.mid<-ggplot(dfm,aes(x=1,y=Var1))+
  geom_text(aes(label= Var2),fontface=2)+
  geom_segment(aes(x=0.94,xend=0.96,yend=Var1))+
  geom_segment(aes(x=1.04,xend=1.065,yend=Var1))+
  ggtitle("")+
  ylab(NULL)+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0),limits=c(0.94,1.065))+
  scale_y_discrete(labels=c("F2" = "Dose 0.5", "F10" = "Dose 1",
                            "F21" = "Dose 2"))+
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(),
        panel.grid=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        panel.background=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(color=NA),
        axis.ticks.x=element_line(color=NA),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,-1,1,-1), "mm"))
g1 <- ggplot(data = dfm, aes(x = Var1, y = Freq.x)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + ggtitle("Number of sales staff") + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Var1, y = Freq.x),shape=19,size=6,color="red")+
  expand_limits(y =600) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,-1,1,0), "mm")) + 
  scale_y_reverse() + coord_flip() 
g2 <- ggplot(data = dfm, aes(x = Var1, y = Freq.y)) +xlab(NULL)+ 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + ggtitle("Sales (x $1000)") + 
  geom_point(aes(x = Var1, y = Freq.y),shape=19,size=6,color="blue")+
  expand_limits(y =600) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
        plot.margin = unit(c(1,0,1,-1), "mm")) + 
  coord_flip() 
library(gridExtra) 
gg1 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g1)) 
gg2 <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g2)) 
gg.mid <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(g.mid)) 

grid.arrange(gg1,gg.mid,gg2,ncol=3,widths=c(4/9,1/9,4/9))
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: The same scale of X axis for the right and the left sides?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131536/discussion-between-derive111-and-nik).

Comment: I accepted your answer. is it possible to tell me how i make the labels bold? and also add a text ? if you add this, I will like your answer too

Comment: Update Nº4 for bold labels... for text? an example?

Answer (score 2):

Look at `levels(dfm$Var1)`. It causes your problem. You need to change its order. (I don't have a good idea about ellipses.)

```
library(dplyr)

ind <- gsub("F", "", dfm$Var1) %>% as.numeric() %>% order(decreasing = T)
newlev <- levels(dfm$Var1)[ind]
dfm$Var1 <- factor(dfm$Var1, levels = newlev)
```

[image]