# Is it possible to make 2 facet_wraped bar graph grow from the same base?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bar-chart

The graph I made is this? But I have tried many things to make the barplot grow from the same base.

[image]

I need my graph to look like this.

[image]

as I mentioned earlier I have tried doing basic things But I haven't found a way to make the graph grow from the same base.

Comment: Hello Jickson. What do you mean with "grow from the same base"?
Also, you must [share](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a reproducible example.

Comment: Hey Ric, The first graph is the one I made, But I want my graph to look like the second one,

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/50064587/8391095